# Remove 3 dots from the end of excerpt in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this front page showing three texts, but it all ends with "..." which is okay all other places than this particular place. The post type for these three texts is services, why I have modified the code as below.

```
// The excerpt based on words
/* Original disabled by Kenn Nielsen
function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words).'...';
}
*/

// Created if statement to remove dots from services on frontpage 

if (post_type_exists('services') ) {
    function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
        $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
        if(count($words) > $word_limit)
        array_pop($words);
        return implode(' ', $words).'';
    }
} else {
    function my_string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
        $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
        if(count($words) > $word_limit)
        array_pop($words);
        return implode(' ', $words).'...';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working as expected. Is there something I'm missing? 
I'm sure this could be done in shorter code, but I choose the quick way.

Best, 
Kenn

A work-around:

Fixed it with the easiest solution without changing the theme-function.php and the way it change the excerpt to show three dots if wordcount has been given.

In the widget, the code used for displaying the content is:

```
        <div class="post_content">
        <?php if ( $instance['excerpt'] ) : ?>
          <?php if($limittext=="" || $limittext==0){ ?>
              <?php if ( $instance['excerpt_as_link'] ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              <?php if ( $instance['excerpt_as_link'] ) : ?>
                </a>
              <?php endif; ?>
          <?php }else{ ?>
              <?php if ( $instance['excerpt_as_link'] ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$limittext);?>
              <?php if ( $instance['excerpt_as_link'] ) : ?>
                </a>
              <?php endif; ?>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

The way was to echo without the function, so

```
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo my_string_limit_words($excerpt,$limittext);?>
```

will be

```
<?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo $excerpt;?>
```

And this solved the issue/request.

Comment: "*Unfortunately this is not working as expected.*" — How are we supposed to know how *you* expected it to work? What works? What doesn't? Please include all the relevant details.

Comment: AFAIK, You can't have conditioned function declaration, try adding the condition inside the function: `return implode(' ', $words). (post_type_exists('services') ? '' : '...');`

Comment: Are you using the_content() or the_excerpt() to display content on this page?

Comment: I'm sorry @AmalMurali I was a little bit to quick I think.
I want to remove the three dots at the end of the excerpts for post type 'services'. 
All other excerpts in other post types should not be affected. 
How I expected to work was, if the post type = 'services' then it should return nothing at the end, if not 'services' then add three dots..

Comment: @JayBhatt
See http://tinypic.com/r/2cgygbm/8
This is from the widget creating the post.

Comment: @KennNielsen Your passing the excerpt to your my_string_limit_words() function. Try using the excerpt without it.

Comment: @JayBhatt Thanks! That solved it. I have updated the question. Otherwise, please make an answer that I can accept, for other users to see :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your using the_excerpt() to display the contents.

Add the function below to your function.php file.

```
function change_excerpt( $more ) {
        if(post_type_exists('services')){
           return '';
        }
     return '...';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'change_excerpt'); //Wordpress 2.8+
```

Comment: Didn't even think of doing it this way. +1

Comment: I have added the above function to functions.php and changed the other part back to the original.
This did not remove the dots though. Do I need to change elsewhere?

Comment: Just one thing here, your else statement is missing

Comment: @KennNielsen How are you displaying your contents?

Comment: @JayBhatt See tinypic.com/r/2cgygbm/8 This is from the widget creating the post.

Comment: My +1. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a custom excerpts. You only need to declare it once, but it can be used several times with different lengths. You can just change `the_excerpt();` in your template files with `echo pietergoosen_custom_excerpts($limit);` where `$limit` is the amount of words, like `echo pietergoosen_custom_excerpts(45);` to display 45 words.

Here is the function to achieve that

```
function pietergoosen_custom_excerpts($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit, '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&hellip;' . __( 'Read more &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</a>');
}
```

If you need something else than

```
'<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&hellip;' . __( 'Read more &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</a>'
```

you can just change it. If you need nothing to be displayd after the last word, you can just simply do the following

```
function pietergoosen_custom_excerpts($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code snippet to `function.php` file.

```
function quanda_new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'quanda_new_excerpt_more');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

create new function in

**functions.php**

```
function custom_excerpt() {
 $text=preg_replace( "/\\[&hellip;\\]/",'place here whatever you want to replace',get_the_excerpt());
echo '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
}
```

use the new function on your page.

Answer (score 0):

**Open your theme function.php and add this line**

add_filter('excerpt_more', '__return_false');